# Is there a proper way to use a base64 data-URI image from a CSS style sheet?

Tags: css, background, base64

I'm creating a table containing images and want to refer to the src of the image as a base64 data-URI from a style sheet. This style sheet would contain muliple images encoded. I could do this within the body of the page or in the head, but that makes the document difficult to edit. How should I be coding the image tag in the body and table to refer from the external CSS?

I've tried using the image as a base64 data-URI within the body.

```
<img alt="B" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG..." align="bottom" border="0" height="186" width="120">
```

That works. Also within the head as a style.

I've looked around stackoverflow and other places and found similar code but not with a external CSS file.

```
<!-- within the page body -->
<td style="vertical-align: top; height: 186px; width: 120px;">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"><img src="C" align="bottom" border="0" height="186" width="120"> </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Here is a JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mL5fkung/

As you can see in the 1st row the images are shown in the traditional way.
In the 2nd row I've use the base64 image code in the img code.
The 3rd row shows the desired code that isn't working.

Comment: Thank you for your help and comments.
I may fork this to work on adding multiple td cells with unique uri data images.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will work, if you add the class `C` to each `<img>`:

```
<img src="" align="bottom" border="0" height="186" width="120" class="C" />
```

JSfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/a40qnzuf/

Comment: Using this method may provide the "broken image" icon on top of the background.  You could use a small, transparent image (1x1) as the original source to avoid that.

Comment: I tried
`<td>
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"><img src="http://www.1x1px.me/ffffff-0.0.png" align="bottom" border="0"
height="186" width="120" class="C" /> </div>
</div>
</td>`

But the image won't scale to 120x186

Comment: by adding     

`background-size: contain;` to  .C in the css I get containment.